# さくらVPS上のUbuntu16.04にSoftEtherでVPNサーバを立てたが繋がらない問題

Tags: linux, ubuntu

さくらVPS上のUbuntu16.04上にSoftEtherを使って、VPNサーバを立てたいのですが、

下記の記事を元に設定を行っても、
http://qiita.com/showwin/items/92861057a8b62611444d

Macから繋がろうとした際に、L2TP-VPNサーバが繋がらないという文言が出てきて、

[image: mac_msg]

接続出来ない状態です。

同じ手法で自分のサーバ上にVPNサーバを立てた所、

LAN内では無事繋がることができました。

従って、SoftEtherのVPNサーバそのものはちゃんと立ち上がっていると思います。

vpncmdで、checkコマンドを使ってチェックした所、問題は発見されませんでしたし、

UDPの500と4500番は空けてあります。

どのようにすればさくらVPS上のマシンにVPNで繋がることができるでしょうか？

またはデバックの方法等を教えて頂けると幸いです。

### 2017/04/24 追記

またSoftEtherのログですが、

server_log、security_log、packet_logのすべてのログ・ファイルにおいて、

Macから接続した際には、何もログが残っていない状態です。

おそらくポート等の問題で、vpnサーバそのものにつながってないと思われるのですが、

ufwのステータスを確認すると、下記のようにUDPの500と4500番は空いているようです。

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
5555                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8888                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
500/udp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
4500/udp                   ALLOW       Anywhere
```

さくらvpsのポート開放等、またはNICの設定等で、

問題が発生していると思われるのですが、

詳しい方がいらっしゃったら、デバックの方法を教えて頂けると幸いです。

### 2017/04/26 追記

下記はさくらvpn ubuntuサーバ上で
`netstat -anu`を実施した結果です。
160.1.1.1がグローバルIPとします。実際のIPとは異なります。

```
$ netstat -anu
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:1194          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 160.1.1.1:1194       0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33752           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:500           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 160.1.1.1:500        0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:62043           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34911           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42104           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 160.1.1.1:123        0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:43390           0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:4500          0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 160.1.1.1:4500       0.0.0.0:*                          
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*
```

上記の結果を見ると、500と4500のポートは空いているように思われます。

詳しい方がいらっしゃったら、デバックの方法を教えて頂けると幸いです。

Comment: Softehter vpn のログは見れますか？Macから接続するタイミングでどのようなログが出力されているか質問に追記してみてください。

Comment: @take88 コメントありがとうございます。現状のログの状態を追記させて頂きました。

Comment: `netstat -anu` で 500 と 4500 が 開いているか確認できますでしょうか？

Comment: @take88 まず初めに何度もコメントして頂き、ありがとうございます。助かります。 netstat -anuの出力結果を追記しました。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: たしかにサーバー側は問題なさそうに見受けられます。通信経路上のネットワーク機器で UDP500,4500をブロックしている可能性はありませんか？

Comment: @take88 なるほど、ルータぐらいしか間にいないのですが、外に出る側のfireworkなどは設定していないように思われます。クライアントのmacからnmapでポートスキャンしてみたのですが、filteredと出ているのでさくらのVPS側でまだブロックされている可能性もあるのでしょうか。

Comment: 切り分けとして、vpnserver を stop させた状態で、nmap でポートスキャンすると、結果は closed になりますか？ 到達出来ているなら 到達不能の応答があるはずですので closed になると思います。 filtered になる場合は、ufw を一時的に無効化して 同じようにポートスキャンの結果を見てください。 いずれも filterd となる場合は 通信経路でブロックされていると思います。

Comment: プロバイダがブロックする場合もあるので、さくらと、プロバイダにそれぞれ聞いてみるのも手だと思います。

Comment: @take88 なるほど。今VPNのサーバを止めてnmapしてもfiltered状態であることを確認しました。自宅だけでなく、いくつかの拠点から試しても同じ状態なので、さくらVPSが怪しい気がします。問い合わせしてみようと思います。

Comment: @take88 自己解決しましたので、その結果を回答として記入しました。色々教えて頂き、ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己解決したので、解決方法を書いておきます。
原因はSoftEtherの設定ではなく、
さくらVPSでubuntuを標準インストールすると、
以下のiptableの設定がデフォルト有効になっています。
/etc/iptables/iptables.rules
nfwで追加でiptableを設定しても、設定が反映されず、
上記のファイルを削除して、nfwで設定すると、
500と4500のポートを開けることができました。
その状態だときちんとvpnサーバに接続することができました。

コメントしていただいた @take88さんありがとうございました。